# Exporting to Excel in C#

Tags: c#

I am exporting to excel with the following code, everything is working fine, but one column has text boxes attached with label, only that column's data is not showing up. It is displaying it empty in excel.
I am using asp:GridView.

```
protected void exportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.Charset = "";
            string FileName = "Booking Confirmation " + DateTime.Now + ".xls";
            StringWriter strwritter = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htmltextwrtter = new HtmlTextWriter(strwritter);
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);
            BookingConfirmationList.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
            BookingConfirmationList.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
            BookingConfirmationList.HeaderRow.Cells[0].FindControl("ddlProjectId").Visible = false;
            BookingConfirmationList.HeaderRow.Cells[0].FindControl("ddlBookNo").Visible = false;
            BookingConfirmationList.HeaderRow.Cells[0].FindControl("ddlEngineerBooked").Visible = false;
            BookingConfirmationList.HeaderRow.Cells[0].FindControl("ddlDateBooked").Visible = false;
            BookingConfirmationList.HeaderRow.Cells[0].FindControl("ddlChemicals").Visible = false;
            BookingConfirmationList.HeaderRow.Cells[0].FindControl("ddlQuantityBooked").Visible = false;
            BookingConfirmationList.HeaderRow.Cells[0].FindControl("ddlBatchNo").Visible = false;
            BookingConfirmationList.HeaderRow.Cells[0].FindControl("ddlOperatorName").Visible = false;
            //BookingConfirmationList.HeaderRow.Cells[0].FindControl("chkAllRows").Visible = false;
            //BookingConfirmationList.FindControl("chkRow").Visible = false;



            for (int i = 0; i < BookingConfirmationList.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                GridViewRow row = BookingConfirmationList.Rows[i];
                GridViewRow rowH = BookingConfirmationList.HeaderRow;
                rowH.Cells[0].Visible = false;
                row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
                row.Cells[6].Visible = true;

            }

            BookingConfirmationList.RowStyle.Height = 25;
            BookingConfirmationList.RowStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;

            BookingConfirmationList.RenderControl(htmltextwrtter);
            Response.Write(strwritter.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();

        }
```

[Asp Grid View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOmsX.png)

[Ref Image Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZxxn.png)

Comment: Which column is it?

Comment: column 6 i.e. Quantity Booked. Its a combination of Quantity which is in text box, while unit is in label.

Comment: What's the point of the three `data = [...]` in a row? And why do you do something on the header row for every row?

Comment: can be find cotrol in cell and get thats value...

((TextBox)BookingConfirmationList.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("TextBoxId")).Text;

Comment: i used those 3 data to check something, its not related. but there is a drop down on every header row, so i have to make its risibility to false. so that i doesn't appear on excel.

Comment: Getting value is not an issue, it is not appearing on excel.

Comment: The way you wrote it, you currently are setting the first cell of the `HeaderRow`'s visibility to `false` **n times** where **n** is the number of rows in your `BookingConfirmationList`. Also when pasting your code here, you'd better remove irrelevant parts of code such as those `data = [...]` as it only makes noise. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Post Edited, please check.

Comment: every row in column 6 is empty.

Comment: and please review the reference image.

Comment: Maybe try to set the text of the 6th cell in your loop for every row based on the textboxes' text? `row.Cells[6].Text = textboxValue.Text + " " + textboxUnit.Text:` or something alike

Comment: set it in loop worked, Thanks @Rafalon

Comment: I added it as an answer then as it has nothing to do as a comment if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the text you want for that 6th column, one thing you can do is setting the text in your loop for every row, based on the textboxes' text.

Something like the following:

```
row.Cells[6].Text = textboxValue.Text + " " + textboxUnit.Text;
```